# App não compartilha usando WhatsApp aparece: "Falha ao compartilhar. Pro favor, tente novamente."

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Quando escolho WhatsApp para compartilhar aparece uma mensagem:

> "Falha ao compartilhar. Pro favor, tente novamente."

Meu código está assim:

```
compartilhar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String uriToImage = "http://192.168.0.50/img001.jpeg";

                Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
                shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uriToImage);
                shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, null));

            }
        });
```

Penso que pode ser um problema de permissões. Não sei como resolver. Preciso de ajuda!

Answer (score -1):

Na verdade, o problema está em você tentar compartilhar uma imagem remota como uma stream local. Se lembro bem, o whatsapp permite enviar arquivos por base64 na intent ou a uri de um arquivo local.